# Nativescript Error: Executing webpack failed with exit code 1

Tags: nativescript

I've done a fresh install of Nativescript on a new iMac (running Big Sur) following the instructions carefully (from https://docs.nativescript.org/environment-setup.html#macos-ios).

It was working fine after the install yesterday, but today I cannot run apps in ios simulator (or in an Android virtual device).

The **ns doctor** command in terminal gives me this initially:

```
No issues were detected.
✔ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
✔ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
✔ The Android SDK is installed.
✔ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
✔ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
✔ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
✔ Xcode is installed and is configured properly.
✔ xcodeproj is installed and is configured properly.
✔ CocoaPods are installed.
✔ CocoaPods update is not required.
✔ CocoaPods are configured properly.
✔ Your current CocoaPods version is newer than 1.0.0.
✔ Python installed and configured correctly.
✔ The Python 'six' package is found.
✔ Xcode version 12.5.1 satisfies minimum required version 10.
✔ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
✔ Component nativescript has 8.0.2 version and is up to date.
```

However, when I create a new app (**ns create**) and then try to run in (**ns run ios**), I get this error: *Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.*

The error messages start with this: *TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolved' of undefined.*

The same thing is also happening when I try to run it on Android.

After trying to run it on both ios and Android, **ns doctor** adds these lines:

```
✔ Component @nativescript/core has 8.0.8 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/ios has 8.0.0 version and is up to date.
✔ Component @nativescript/android has 8.0.0 version and is up to date.
```

So it seems like the platforms are being added properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The full error message is:

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
webpack is watching the files...
/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:817
    if (entry.resolved !== undefined) return entry.resolved;
              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolved' of undefined
    at getResolvedTimestamp (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:817:12)
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:1167:21
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:352:5
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at AsyncQueue._handleResult (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:322:21)
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/AsyncQueue.js:305:11
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:3098:21
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:3010:22
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2830:7
    at done (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2925:13)
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/FileSystemInfo.js:2994:23
    at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/fs.js:311:21)
    at runCallbacks (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:27:15)
    at /Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:200:4
    at callback (/Users/student/Desktop/testApp/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:299:20)
Executing webpack failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: It might help to note that apps I created in Nativescript earlier this summer (version 8.0) will still run for me.  Though I can't see any differences with the package.json and webpack.config.js files between the versions, when I copy over the older version of node_modules I can get the newly created apps to run...

Comment: I have already lost 4h today struggling with the very same problem.

Comment: Hi pawel221. Sorry to hear that.  At least it's not just me then lol.  I've spent a lot of time on this too now.  May have to take a break now and see if someone can help us...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this, we have confirmed a breaking change in the latest webpack release:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v5.51.1

You can switch your package.json to use the `rc` as follows to resolve this right now:

```
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@nativescript/webpack": "rc"
},
```

Then `ns clean` and you should be able to run your app now.

We also published another `beta` tag pinning webpack to 5.50.0 so doing `ns clean` without making any other dependency change in your own package.json should also work now.

Comment: Hi Nathan. It is working again now. Thanks for the quick response and for the fix!